# Oracle case expression trying to use column definitions after then

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I am working on a web application that uses Oracle 12c for the RDMS.

I have come to a stop on what I am trying to achieve and so looking for some help/guidance on resolving my issue.

I have the following SQL case statement which runs but returns null values:

```
        CASE MRI.REVIEW_NAME
        WHEN 'wk1' THEN COALESCE(A.DC_CLASSIFICATION_DATE,A.DC_TRANSFER_DATE) + 7
        WHEN 'wk2' THEN COALESCE(A.DC_CLASSIFICATION_DATE,A.DC_TRANSFER_DATE) + 14 
        WHEN 'wk3' THEN COALESCE(A.DC_CLASSIFICATION_DATE,A.DC_TRANSFER_DATE) + 21
        WHEN 'wk4' THEN COALESCE(A.DC_CLASSIFICATION_DATE,A.DC_TRANSFER_DATE) + 28
        WHEN 'wk5' THEN COALESCE(A.DC_CLASSIFICATION_DATE,A.DC_TRANSFER_DATE) + 35
        WHEN 'wk6' THEN COALESCE(A.DC_CLASSIFICATION_DATE,A.DC_TRANSFER_DATE) + 42
        WHEN 'wk7' THEN COALESCE(A.DC_CLASSIFICATION_DATE,A.DC_TRANSFER_DATE) + 49
        WHEN 'wk8' THEN COALESCE(A.DC_CLASSIFICATION_DATE,A.DC_TRANSFER_DATE) + 56
        WHEN 'wk9' THEN COALESCE(A.DC_CLASSIFICATION_DATE,A.DC_TRANSFER_DATE) + 63
        WHEN 'wk10' THEN COALESCE(A.DC_CLASSIFICATION_DATE,A.DC_TRANSFER_DATE) + 70
        WHEN 'wk11' THEN COALESCE(A.DC_CLASSIFICATION_DATE,A.DC_TRANSFER_DATE) + 77
        WHEN 'wk12' THEN COALESCE(A.DC_CLASSIFICATION_DATE,A.DC_TRANSFER_DATE) + 84
        END AS REVIEW_END_DATE,
```

Is this possible to do, all of the examples that I have found use a string value after the THEN and not a column manipulation?
Please no PL/SQL answers, just SQL.

Ok update, the data was causing the issue and now working as expected. Thank you as I have learned something about the Oracle Case statement that I thought wasn't possible.

Any help appreciated.
JC

Comment: You don't have to return string values from a case statement, so more than likely something else is wrong, such as `MRI.REVIEW_NAME` has values of WK1 instead of wk1

Comment: If a CASE returns `NULL` then none of the values matched the content of the column `review_name`.

Comment: If you're getting `NULL` everywhere, I would point to that the `ELSE` condition is happening.  Since you haven't specified one, the default is to return `NULL`.  Please show us some sample data.

Comment: `COALESCE(A.DC_CLASSIFICATION_DATE,A.DC_TRANSFER_DATE) + REGEXP_SUBSTR(MRI.REVIEW_NAME, '\d+$')*7 AS REVIEW_END_DATE` is shorter and perhaps also solves your issue.

Comment: Case _expression_, not _statement_.

Comment: Great solution thank you @Wernfried Domscheit

Comment: Thank you everyone else who commented.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Any chance you could put your comment into an answer so the question can get marked as answered?

Comment: Good lesson learned to never leave out the ELSE.  Always expect the unexpected!

Answer (score 2):

A more generic expression is this one:

```
COALESCE(A.DC_CLASSIFICATION_DATE,A.DC_TRANSFER_DATE) + REGEXP_SUBSTR(MRI.REVIEW_NAME, '\d+$')*7 AS REVIEW_END_DATE
```

It is shorter and should solve your problem.